# Cannot scroll past iframe on iOS/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've got an iframe embedded somewhere halfway down my page that's 100% of the width and height of the screen.

In mobile Safari I can scroll down the page to where the iframe is in regular fashion (finger swipe up). However, as soon as the iframe fills the screen I can no longer scroll. This is of course because all the pointer events are being captured by the iframe.

Is there any way around this? I know events can't bubble up from iframes to their container divs and that there's no way to interact with iframe css cross-domain.

Importantly, the iframe has interactive content so I still need click events to work on it. In other words, putting a transparent div over the iframe won't work either.

Any thoughts?